# Adding Ellipsis on last line of every fixed height paragraph with overflow-y hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, overflow, liquid, ellipsis

I've about 10 paragraph of description text, it has fix height with text-overflow y: hidden.

I have added JQuery script to add Ellipsis at the 'last line' of 'each paragraph'.

However the script only works for the first paragraph of description text. 
How can I make it works for the other paragraphs of text?

```
<div class="description" style="height:85px; overflow-y:hidden;" itemprop="description">
  <a id="a" href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}" itemprop="url"> 
    {{ product.description| strip_html  }}  
  </a>
</div>

<script>
  var $p = $('.description #a');
  var divh = $('.description').height();
  while ($p.outerHeight() > divh) {
  $p.text(function (index, text) {
    return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
  });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just throw it in a loop.

```
$('.description #a').each(function() {
  var $p = $(this);
  var divh = $('.description').height();
  while ($p.outerHeight() > divh) {
    $p.text(function (index, text) {
      return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
    });
  }
});
```

This assumes all your div's have the same class and your  anchors have the same id.  If you need to make it more generic just do:

```
$('div a').each(function() {
    //Rest of code here
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mewcg3zo/1/